# Sort array of Dicts by multiple keys, in Julia

Tags: arrays, sorting, dictionary, julia

I have a large array of `Dict`s that all look like this

```
{
  "id": 12345,
  "user_id": "6789",
  "question_id": "some_question_id",
  "correct": "true",
  "actions": "...",
  "consequentiality": 0,
  "timestamp": 1505123456.000
}
```

and I need to sort them by `(question_id, user_id, id, consequentiality)` with `question_id` moving the slowest, and `consequentiality` moving the faster -- kind of like grouping and subgrouping, if you will, but I need to perform swaps on an ordered array in certain cases, and most of these tend to happen across groups. I've been playing around with `Base.sort`, passing different functions to `by` and `lt`. The best I came up with is combining multiple sorts one inside the other and passing the different keys to each `by` clause, something like

```
sort(sort(sort(sort(df, by=x->x["question_id"]), by=x->x["user_id"] ...
```

you get the picture. So far I haven't been able to reach a satisfactory stable ordering, even when using a stable algorithm such as `MergeSort`.

Help?

**EDIT** Would it make sense to use a tuple in the `by` clause? How do I reverse the ordering of a non-numeric element, though?

Comment: Try `sort(df, by=x->getindex.(x,("question_id", "user_id", "id", "consequentiality")))`

Comment: Regarding reversing the order of non-numeric value, this may require a custom less-than function in an `lt=` parameter.

Comment: Regarding the `getindex`, it works, thanks. Is it the same as specifying the keys in a tuple? Regarding the `lt` function, do I make an and-chain or do I need something more sophisticated? Because when I tried the and-chain earlier, I couldn't get the relative orderings I wanted. Will having the `getindex` (or tuple?) help?

Comment: To reverse sort a non-numeric username field, for example, you can do: `sort(df, lt=(x,y)->lexless((x["question_id],false,x["id"]),(y["ques‌​tion_id],x["username"]>y["username"],y["id"‌​])))`. This sorts first by `question_id`, then reverse sorts by `username` and then sorts by `id` (the trick is comparing false to the greater-than expression on `username` which reverses the order)

Comment: OK, with your latest edit (swap true and false and change sign of the comparison) I can get everything in order. I was getting confused because `"id"` was coming out the wrong way around and I couldn't reverse it.

Comment: Now, the task is to make it look nicer, check the efficiency and perhaps define a function to make this cleaner.

Comment: @DanGetz the `sort(df, by=x->getindex.(x,("question_id", "user_id", "id", "consequentiality")))` comment no longer seems to work! Do you know if it was deprecated or something? Or was it intended to be used on dataframes, not dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demonstration of a method to cleanup the solution using `lt=...` in the comments. Note this works only with tuples, as it redefines `isless` for tuples. If there is enthusiasm, maybe something like this can be incorporated into Julia or some package.

```
julia> struct RevNext
       end

julia> import Base: isless

julia> function isless(t1::Tuple, t2::Tuple)
           n1, n2 = length(t1), length(t2)
           reverse = false
           for i = 1:min(n1, n2)
               a, b = t1[i], t2[i]
               if !isequal(a, b)
                   return reverse ? isless(b, a) : isless(a,b)
               else
                   reverse = isa(a,RevNext)
               end
           end
           return n1 < n2
       end
WARNING: Method definition isless(Tuple, Tuple) ...
isless (generic function with 53 methods)
```

And to use it, we write `sort(M,by=x->(x[:b], RevNext(), x[:a]))`. An example for a randomly generated vector `M`:

```
julia> M = [Dict(:a=>rand(),:b=>rand(Bool)) for i=1:10]
10-element Array{Dict{Symbol,Any},1}:
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.735352),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, true)) 
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.537437),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, true)) 
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.314947),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, true)) 
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.9723),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, false))  
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.605042),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, true)) 
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.256509),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, false))
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.133487),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, false))
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.320249),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, false))
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.409549),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, true)) 
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.421471),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, true)) 

julia> sort(M,by=x->(x[:b], RevNext(), x[:a]))
10-element Array{Dict{Symbol,Any},1}:
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.9723),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, false))  
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.320249),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, false))
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.256509),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, false))
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.133487),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, false))
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.735352),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, true)) 
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.605042),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, true)) 
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.537437),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, true)) 
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.421471),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, true)) 
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.409549),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, true)) 
 Dict{Symbol,Any}(Pair{Symbol,Any}(:a, 0.314947),Pair{Symbol,Any}(:b, true))
```

Comment: I think I prefer the other solution better. Both are a bit clunky, but the other one was more compact, and just as general (not very) as this one – at least it doesn't involve parameters that vary the semantics of neighboring parameters. Originally, I was hoping that the `rev` parameter of `sort` accepted a tuple of booleans to reverse or not the tuple passed in `by`.