# How to sort a list of dictionaries based on multiple keys in Julia

Tags: dictionary, sorting, julia

```
rows = [Dict("fname" =>  "Brian", "lname" =>  "Jones", "uid" =>  1003),
    Dict("fname" =>  "David", "lname" =>  "Beazley", "uid" =>  1002),
    Dict("fname" =>  "John", "lname" =>  "Cleese", "uid" =>  1001),
    Dict("fname" =>  "Big", "lname" =>  "Jones", "uid" =>  1004)]
    
sort(rows, by=x->getindex.(x,("lname", "fname")))
```

is giving error:

```
  ERROR: ArgumentError: broadcasting over dictionaries and `NamedTuple`s is reserved
Stacktrace:
  [1] broadcastable(#unused#::Dict{String, Any})
    @ Base.Broadcast .\broadcast.jl:683
  [2] broadcasted
    @ .\broadcast.jl:1312 [inlined]
  [3] (::var"#1#2")(x::Dict{String, Any})
    @ Main .\REPL[2]:1
  [4] lt(o::Base.Order.By{var"#1#2", Base.Order.ForwardOrdering}, a::Dict{String, Any}, b::Dict{String, Any})
    @ Base.Order .\ordering.jl:111
  [5] sort!
    @ .\sort.jl:502 [inlined]
  [6] sort!(v::Vector{Dict{String, Any}}, lo::Int64, hi::Int64, a::Base.Sort.MergeSortAlg, o::Base.Order.By{var"#1#2", B
ase.Order.ForwardOrdering}, t::Vector{Dict{String, Any}})
    @ Base.Sort .\sort.jl:587
  [7] sort!
    @ .\sort.jl:586 [inlined]
  [8] sort!
    @ .\sort.jl:657 [inlined]
  [9] #sort!#8
    @ .\sort.jl:717 [inlined]
 [10] #sort#9
    @ .\sort.jl:764 [inlined]
 [11] top-level scope
    @ REPL[2]:1
```

How to sort out this error.

Related : [Sort array of Dicts by multiple keys, in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975361/sort-array-of-dicts-by-multiple-keys-in-julia)

From the comments provided in the above link only I tried the above solution.

Comment: the code Dan shared in that answer is quite old, and I wonder if perhaps Julia has moved on from then. It doesn't actually work on the example input OP gave

Comment: @Mark `sort(rows, by = x -> (x["lname"], x["fname"]))` works

Comment: The correct way to fix the code in the question is: `sort(rows, by=x->getindex.(Ref(x),("lname", "fname")))`. The related question is using a DataFrame and not an Array, which avoids the error, and thus it is  "still correct" (even if it is old).

Comment: @DanGetz the linked question is quite odd, because the title says it is an 'array of Dicts', but the code itself refers to the array as `df`, which would make me think maybe the OP got confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort by multiple keys, you can use:

```
sort(rows, by = x -> (x["lname"], x["fname"]))
```

Output:

```
4-element Vector{Dict{String, Any}}:
 Dict("lname" => "Beazley", "uid" => 1002, "fname" => "David")
 Dict("lname" => "Cleese", "uid" => 1001, "fname" => "John")
 Dict("lname" => "Jones", "uid" => 1004, "fname" => "Big")
 Dict("lname" => "Jones", "uid" => 1003, "fname" => "Brian")
```

An alternative is using `Ref(x)`, as detailed by Dan Getz below.

Comment: The thing he was actually looking for is `sort(rows, by=x->getindex.(Ref(x),("lname", "fname")))`

Comment: @DanGetz thanks for that! I didn't know about `Ref(x)`